# VBA match 6 Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

The script fills an array from a sheet called "Tigers" with 6 strings. Then it is supposed to compare that array to a differnt sheet titled "Elephants" and tell me if it finds an exact match. The troublesome code is found at the Application.Match method

Any help understanding how to correctly script a match with multiple values would be appreciated.

```
Sub matchData()

Dim arrCompare(5) As Variant
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim varRes As Variant

Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set shtTigers = Worksheets("Tigers").Range("A2:A100")
Set shtElephants = Worksheets("Elephants").Range("A2:A100")

Sheets("Elephants").Activate

For intRow = 2 To 100

arrCompare(0) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 1).Value      
arrCompare(1) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 2).Value      
arrCompare(2) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 4).Value      
arrCompare(3) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 5).Value      
arrCompare(4) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 7).Value      
arrCompare(5) = Worksheets("Elephants").Cells(intRow, 9).Value      

'compare all 6 strings in array against Elephant sheet rows for a match
varRes = Application.Match(arrCompare(), shtTigers, 0)

'also tried
'varRes = Application.Match(((arrCompare(0))*((arrCompare(1))*((arrCompare(2)) * ((arrCompare(3)) * ((arrCompare(4)) * ((arrCompare(5))*((arrCompare(6)),shtTigers, 0)

'messagebox just gives a Error 13 or 2042 for varRes
MsgBox ("varRes = " & varRes)

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Match requires a single lookup value but you're trying to pass the whole array. Iterate one element at at time instead:

```
Dim counter as Integer

    For x = 0 to 5
         If Not IsError(Application.Match(arrCompare(x), shtTigers, 0)) Then
              counter = counter + 1
         End If
    Next x

If counter = 6 Then Debug.Print "Matches found"
```

Comment: For a "match" to occur the entire row must contain these 6 strings. If I iterate one element at a time then the result would give false matches as these 6 strings may be in the range "shtTigers" but not on the same row.

Comment: Then just add a counter, as above